# Windows batch - Check if a bunch of IPs are online and sort them into the online ones

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, dns

I need to check a bunch of IPs (DNSes) to see if they are online, and sort them into only the working ones.

Example:

input: `8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 1.1.1.1 32.45.76.54 208.67.222.222`

output: `8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 208.67.222.222`

Here is what I have so far:

```
set dns=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 1.1.1.1 32.45.76.54 208.67.222.222
set olddns=%dns%
set lastdns=0
set dnsnumber=1

:startdns
for /f "tokens=%dnsnumber%" %%i in ("%dns%") do set pickeddns=%%i
call:checkip %pickeddns%
if /i "%dnsstatus%"=="up" set /a dnsnumber=%dnsnumber%+1
if /i "%dnsstatus%"=="down" (for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%dns%") do set dns=%%b)
if /i "%lastdns%"=="%pickeddns%" goto :AddDNS
set lastdns=%pickeddns%
goto :startdns

:AddDNS
echo %dns%
pause

:checkip
cls
set ip=%~1
ping -n 1 -w 2000 %ip% | find "TTL"
if not errorlevel 1 set dnsstatus=up
if errorlevel 1 set dnsstatus=down
cls
goto :eof
```

I think the problem is in the

```
if /i "%dnsstatus%"=="down" (for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%dns%") do set dns=%%b)
```

because I want it to remove the not working DNS, but instead, it removes the first DNS in the list.
 Anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Ugh.  This can be shortened by a lot  Your are using the wrong FOR command which is causing you to use too much extra code.  To really fix your code you would just do string substitution by removing the ip address from the DNS variable. examle: `set DNS=!DNS:%%b=!`. This would require you to enable delayed expansion as well.  Regardless of that I will post a much shortened version of your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.  It does leave an extra space though when removing from the main DNS variable.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set dns=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 1.1.1.1 32.45.76.54 208.67.222.222
set olddns=%dns%

:startdns
for %%G in (%olddns%) do (
    ping -n 1 -w 2000 %%G | find "TTL" >nul 2>&1
    if errorlevel 1 set "dns=!dns:%%G=!"
)
echo %dns%
pause

goto :eof
```

Comment: Just asking, is it possible to get the DNS without the extra spaces? I was going to ping each of the DNS and find out which two DNS had the lowest ping, and then add them using netsh commands. Is this even possible to do this?

Comment: @djmrminer, the extra space should not cause any issues with that.

Comment: `ping` command can show [errors](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc952252.aspx) that contain the `TTL` string. It is safer to use `TTL=`